# Building Pandas DataFrame with minute level OHLCV data containing 'Time' column in 930, 931, 932...17:28, 17:29, 17:30 format

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have minute resolution stock data in this format

> 19980102 930 3.29473 3.30923 3.29473 3.29473 76119.2 4 0 0

Where the columns are 
'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Split Factor', 'Earnings', 'Dividends'

(lines are terminated with 0x0A (Linefeed)  not CR LF. It looks like pandas.read_csv copes with reading this data reasonably well.)

The data comes from a company called www.QuantQuote.com

I'm quite new to Pandas and python but I've read "Python for Data Analysis" by Wes McKinney. This is my first python project but I've written C, C++, C#, assembler etc code for many years.

My objective has been to create a DataFrame for each stock with the Date and Time combined into a TimeSeries "DateTime" index. I then intend to resample this to Daily and Monthly DataFrames.

I've tried various ways to get pandas.read_csv to read this in one step but I cant find a way to get it to read the 'Time' column. Its in a strange

> 930, 931, 932...17:28, 17:29, 17:30

format

Is there a better way to do this ? I was hoping to read the data in with a single call to _read_csv if possible

Here is what I have so far.

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd

import os

mypath = "c:\PythonStuff\QuantQuoteData\table_aapl.txt"
columnHeadings = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Split Factor', 'Earnings', 'Dividends']

minData = pd.read_csv(mypath, names=columnHeadings, dtype= {"Date":str, "Time":str}, parse_dates = False, sep=' ')

minData["Time"] = minData["Time"].map(lambda x : x[:-2] + ":" + x[-2:] + ":00+00:00")
minData["DateTimeStr"] = minData["Date"] + " " + minData["Time"]
minData["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(minData["DateTimeStr"])

minData.index = minData["DateTime"]
```

Here are the first few lines of the "table_aapl.txt" file

> 19980102 930 3.29473 3.30923 3.29473 3.29473 76119.2 4 0 0 19980102
>   931 3.29473 3.29473 3.2778 3.29473 263522 4 0 0 19980102 932 3.29473
>   3.29473 3.2778 3.29473 120384 4 0 0 19980102 933 3.29473 3.29473 3.2633 3.2633 82738.3 4 0 0 19980102 934 3.2633 3.29473 3.2633 3.2778 11169.6 4 0 0 19980102 935 3.29473 3.29473 3.2778 3.2778 11997 4 0 0 19980102 936 3.2633 3.29473 3.2633 3.2778 109628 4 0 0

Any help is greatly appreciated

---

EDIT: Finally, Here is the best solution I could come up with. Everything is obvious in retrospect :)

Thanks for the help :)

```
columnHeadings = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Split Factor', 'Earnings', 'Dividends']

minData = pd.read_csv(
    myFile,
    header = None,
    names = columnHeadings, 
    parse_dates = [["Date", "Time"]],
    date_parser = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H%M'), 
    index_col = "Date_Time",
    sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem using your code but the following worked for me and should work for you with some minor tweaks, the important step here is using strptime to create the datetime from string:

import the data:

```
minData = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data.txt', parse_dates = [[0,1]], header=None,sep=' ')
minData
Out[17]:
            0_1        2        3        4        5         6  7  8  9  10
0  19980102 930  3.29473  3.30923  3.29473  3.29473   76119.2  4  0  0 NaN
1  19980102 931  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  263522.0  4  0  0 NaN
2  19980102 932  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  120384.0  4  0  0 NaN
3  19980102 933  3.29473  3.29473  3.26330  3.26330   82738.3  4  0  0 NaN
4  19980102 934  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780   11169.6  4  0  0 NaN
5  19980102 935  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.27780   11997.0  4  0  0 NaN
6  19980102 936  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780  109628.0  4  0  0 NaN

[7 rows x 10 columns]

#now convert the string using datetime.datetime.strptime:
# rename the first column (may not be necessary for you)
In [20]:

minData.rename(columns={'0_1':columnHeadings[0], 1:columnHeadings[1]},inplace=True)
minData
Out[20]:
           Date        2        3        4        5         6  7  8  9  10
0  19980102 930  3.29473  3.30923  3.29473  3.29473   76119.2  4  0  0 NaN
1  19980102 931  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  263522.0  4  0  0 NaN
2  19980102 932  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  120384.0  4  0  0 NaN
3  19980102 933  3.29473  3.29473  3.26330  3.26330   82738.3  4  0  0 NaN
4  19980102 934  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780   11169.6  4  0  0 NaN
5  19980102 935  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.27780   11997.0  4  0  0 NaN
6  19980102 936  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780  109628.0  4  0  0 NaN

[7 rows x 10 columns]
# now use strptime to format the string into a datetime object
In [21]:

import datetime
minData['Date'] = minData['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H%M'))
minData
Out[21]:
                 Date        2        3        4        5         6  7  8  9  \
0 1998-01-02 09:30:00  3.29473  3.30923  3.29473  3.29473   76119.2  4  0  0   
1 1998-01-02 09:31:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  263522.0  4  0  0   
2 1998-01-02 09:32:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  120384.0  4  0  0   
3 1998-01-02 09:33:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.26330  3.26330   82738.3  4  0  0   
4 1998-01-02 09:34:00  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780   11169.6  4  0  0   
5 1998-01-02 09:35:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.27780   11997.0  4  0  0   
6 1998-01-02 09:36:00  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780  109628.0  4  0  0   

   10  
0 NaN  
1 NaN  
2 NaN  
3 NaN  
4 NaN  
5 NaN  
6 NaN  

[7 rows x 10 columns]
#confirm that we have converted the dates:
In [22]:

minData.dtypes
Out[22]:
Date    datetime64[ns]
2              float64
3              float64
4              float64
5              float64
6              float64
7                int64
8                int64
9                int64
10             float64
dtype: object
```

You can then set the index:

```
In [24]:

minData.set_index('Date')
Out[24]:
                          2        3        4        5         6   7   8   9   \
Date                                                                            
1998-01-02 09:30:00  3.29473  3.30923  3.29473  3.29473   76119.2   4   0   0   
1998-01-02 09:31:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  263522.0   4   0   0   
1998-01-02 09:32:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  120384.0   4   0   0   
1998-01-02 09:33:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.26330  3.26330   82738.3   4   0   0   
1998-01-02 09:34:00  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780   11169.6   4   0   0   
1998-01-02 09:35:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.27780   11997.0   4   0   0   
1998-01-02 09:36:00  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780  109628.0   4   0   0   

                     10  
Date                     
1998-01-02 09:30:00 NaN  
1998-01-02 09:31:00 NaN  
1998-01-02 09:32:00 NaN  
1998-01-02 09:33:00 NaN  
1998-01-02 09:34:00 NaN  
1998-01-02 09:35:00 NaN  
1998-01-02 09:36:00 NaN  

[7 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Aha - I've just understood what you're doing here.. Much better than I had!! ((sorry I find this editor on stackoverflow is really awkward!) I'll try this method now. Really I'd prefer if the answer from user xndrme would work because it seems neater.

Comment: @JasonEdinburgh user @xndrme's answer probably will work fine, however, there are some cases where the parser will just fail and you have to define the format string yourself. In these situations you have to use strptime and this is what I almost always do because I have better control over the outcome, rather than try the dateutil parser and then see if it fails. You can define the lambda as a function and set this as the parser arg in read_csv like this: `pd.read_csv(path, date_parser=my_date_parser)` will work as a notional example

Comment: I finally got this to work! I put everything in its own new editor window and the problems I was having disappeared. Here's the output I get ... http://www.dowce.com/~ZqT My only confusion is whether this is actually indexed by the new Date column or not ?

Comment: @JasonEdinburgh no it is not using this as an index, to do that do this: `minData.set_index('Date')`, you can confirm by doing this `minData.index` it will output the values

Comment: fantastic !!! I was always doing this wrong - I was doing minData.index = minData["Date"].. which just made a mess of things !

Comment: @JasonEdinburgh glad this helped, I only looked at Pandas for a few months and it is one of the best written libraries I have found, plus many devs and users answer questions very quickly on SO

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 import pandas as pd
import dateutil.parser as parser

def f(d):
    if len(d)==12:
        d = d[:9]+"0"+d[9:]
    return parser.parse(d)

columnHeadings = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Split Factor', 'Earnings', 'Dividends']
minData = pd.read_csv("table_aapl.txt", names=columnHeadings, sep=' ', parse_dates=[[0,1]], index_col=0, date_parser=f)

print minData
```

Output:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close    Volume  \
Date_Time                                                           
1998-01-02 09:30:00  3.29473  3.30923  3.29473  3.29473   76119.2   
1998-01-02 09:31:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  263522.0   
1998-01-02 09:32:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  120384.0   
1998-01-02 09:33:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.26330  3.26330   82738.3   
1998-01-02 09:34:00  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780   11169.6   
1998-01-02 09:35:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.27780   11997.0   
1998-01-02 09:36:00  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780  109628.0   

                     Split Factor  Earnings  Dividends  
Date_Time                                               
1998-01-02 09:30:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:31:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:32:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:33:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:34:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:35:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:36:00             4         0          0  

[7 rows x 8 columns]
```

Well, I've just tried with a two arguments function and it receives two arrays of values so I've managed to do this:

```
def g(d,t):
    res = []
    for dd,tt in zip(d,t):                
        date_time = dd
        if len(tt)==3:
            date_time += " 0"
        else:
            date_time += " "
        date_time += tt
        res.append(parser.parse(date_time))
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(res)
```

Now just call `pd.read_csv` as `pd.read_csv("table_aapl.txt", names=columnHeadings, sep=' ', parse_dates=[[0,1]], index_col=0, date_parser=g)`

Output:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close    Volume  \
Date_Time                                                           
1998-01-02 09:30:00  3.29473  3.30923  3.29473  3.29473   76119.2   
1998-01-02 09:31:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  263522.0   
1998-01-02 09:32:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.29473  120384.0   
1998-01-02 09:33:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.26330  3.26330   82738.3   
1998-01-02 09:34:00  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780   11169.6   
1998-01-02 09:35:00  3.29473  3.29473  3.27780  3.27780   11997.0   
1998-01-02 09:36:00  3.26330  3.29473  3.26330  3.27780  109628.0   

                     Split Factor  Earnings  Dividends  
Date_Time                                               
1998-01-02 09:30:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:31:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:32:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:33:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:34:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:35:00             4         0          0  
1998-01-02 09:36:00             4         0          0  

[8 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do.. cunning !I get an error I'll try to work out how to paste it here

Comment: I cant see how to post the entire stack trace here. This is the last part
C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\date_converters.pyc in generic_parser(parse_func, *cols)
     35     for i in xrange(N):
     36         args = [c[i] for c in cols]
---> 37         results[i] = parse_func(*args)
     38 
     39     return results

TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) 

In [32]:

Comment: Could you try `def f(d,e):\n print d,e\n ... #the rest the same`? just to see what is being passed to `f`. I can't figure it out, I copy-paste the code from answer again to my shell and it runs fine :(

Comment: I think I just missed out the line at the top "import dateutil.parser as parser"

Comment: But now you need to try with the original `f` function or with the `g` function I've posted later, maybe pandas choice how to call the function based on how it works. Try with the one argument `f` or the two argument `g`.

Comment: It nearly works - http://www.dowce.com/~Zqt I cant see why the column names arent working. and it doesnt seem to be indexed by the new Date column

Comment: this works! Thank you.  I call minData.set_index and I get the same result as I was looking for - but I think the version with strptime might be safer than the hand crafted g method.. But I never knew how to write a method in that way so this answer has been a big help for me! Many thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, Well, reading http://www.dowce.com/~Zqt I see there are 8 data columns, so if `Date` is not the index what else it could be? Also try with `... parse_dates=[['Date','Time']], index_col='Date_Time',...` to see if now it keeps the column names. I really don't know what's happening, for me all the alternatives are working fine, even with the one argument `f` :(

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didnt know how to call read_csv with a hand crafted parser method and - and you've shown me 2 ways ! I think thats the best way to solve this. I'll keep experimenting :)